# Center of CAGradientLayer returns wrong position on rotate animation

Tags: ios, swift, cashapelayer, caanimation, cagradientlayer

I have a circle like in Instagram profile image which has story. I want to have an affect like circle is spinning. For that, I used `CABasicAnimation`. It is spinning but not in center.

As I searched, I need to give bounty for shapeLayer but when I do that, It doesn't placed where It needs to be.

**How can I achieve** animation like in Instagram story circle (like circle is spinning)?

**EDIT** I also try to add `"colors"` animation but because It works like It is in square, I can't get the desired result.

```
func addCircle() {
    let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: self.bounds.midX, y: self.bounds.midY), radius: self.bounds.width / 2, startAngle: -CGFloat.pi / 2, endAngle: 2 * CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)

    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 10
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    shapeLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
    shapeLayer.strokeEnd = 1.0

    gradient.frame = circularPath.bounds
    gradient.colors = [UIColor.blue.cgColor, UIColor.red.cgColor]
    gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1)
    gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0)

    shapeLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
    gradient.mask = shapeLayer
    self.layer.addSublayer(gradient)

}

let rotationAnimation: CAAnimation = {
    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
    animation.fromValue = 0
    animation.toValue = 1
    animation.duration = 4
    animation.repeatCount = MAXFLOAT
    return animation
}()

@objc private func handleTap() {
        print("Attempting to animate stroke")
        shapeLayer.add(rotationAnimation, forKey: "urSoBasic2")
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If spinning, why not spin  `gradient`

```
   let rotationAnimation: CAAnimation = {
    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
    animation.fromValue = 0
    animation.toValue = Float.pi * 2
    animation.duration = 4
    animation.repeatCount = MAXFLOAT

    return animation
}()

@objc  func handleTap() {
    print("Attempting to animate stroke")
    gradient.add(rotationAnimation, forKey: "urSoBasic2")
}
```

As to off center problem. The correct frame for gradient should be like this :

```
  gradient.frame = self.bounds
```

To verify the center, you may add a background for the view:

```
 self.background = UIColor.black.
```

The reason is `width` and `height` of the view is not set well due to the constraints.  Try to set the correct bounds of the view, so when you add the circularPath, it's center in the view.